# Spotify API: Request with PHP

Tags: json, api, url, spotify

I'am programming with the Spotify Search API. To show the results on my webpage I use PHP and the API in JSON format.

My question is: How can I give Spotify OAuth Token in PHP? How can I make this in the URL? For Example:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=Song&type=track&offset=0&limit=50&token=[MY TOKEN]

Thanks a lot for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot. You have to send the key with POST. You are talking about a GET request. You can do that with cURL. [Read this.](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/)

`$headers = ['Accept: application/json',
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: Bearer '.$access['access_token'].''];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`